# Vulkan: Is the first acquired image at index 0?

Tags: vulkan

When you acquire an image from the swapchain for the first time in a Vulkan application, is the index of that image 0? or is it undefined?

Answer (score 0):

`vkAcquireNextImageKHR` tells you which image you get to use. The first call is not a special case.

Comment: teh spec: "The order in which images are acquired is implementation-dependent, and **may** be different than the order the images were presented."